# Hellp me about error in reportviewr in wpf Please

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, report

i am working on wpf project but when i using the reportviewr for display a report from database will showing this error please help me :\ ;
Thanks for you
this code link :
https://repl.it/repls/KosherSeveralFilename
[image]

Comment: the code is very big

Comment: Please , Hellp me :\

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the dll Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll is in the executable folder.

Comment: Yes i have this file

Comment: Please , Hellp me :\

Comment: Try to catch the complete error stack, so may I can help you. But first try to call this._reportViewer.Reset() before load the parameters.

Comment: ErrorAn unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.MissingReportSourceException' occurred in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll

Additional information: The source of the report definition has not been specified

Comment: i using the 'ReportEmbeddedResource' to import the report rdlc file .

Comment: Please, Hellp me and Thanks for you sir